# Calculating a cumulative series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I could do this on a calculator but I thought there would be a more efficient way to do this than punching on my calculator the following:

> $3.5 \cdot 1.03 + 3.5 \cdot 1.03^2 + 3.5 \cdot 1.03^3 + \ldots + 3.5 \cdot 1.03^{10}$

So basically,

> $xy + xy^2 + xy^3 + ... + xy^{10}$

How can I simplify this to make it easier to calculate on a calculator?

Comment: This is a geometric series.

Comment: $$x\cdot\frac{y^{11}-1}{y-1}$$

Comment: Standard geometric series or progression. You can look up the formula for the sum in any number of places or even derive it from first principles. The solution to your problem is scary for several reasons, but unrelated to the underlying math :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a finite geometric series. It has a formula. Let's derive it.

Let $$S = a + a(r)+ a(r)^2 + \dots + a(r)^n.$$

With this set up the quantity you seek is $S - a$, since you don't want the first term. Let's get a formula for $S$ and then just subtract $a$.

Multiplying $S$ and $r$ gives $$Sr = a(r) + \dots + a(r)^{n+1}.$$

Then the difference $$Sr - S = a(r)^{n+1} - a.$$ If that step is not clear, write it out term by term and do the subtraction to see everything cancel except for what is on the right hand side above. Now factor to get $$S(r-1) = a(r)^{n+1} - a$$ which we can divide to to yield $$S = \frac{a(r)^{n+1} - a}{r-1}.$$ So now subtract $a$ to get the value you want, $$S - a = \frac{a(r)^{n+1} - a}{r-1} - a = a \cdot \frac{r^{n+1} - r}{r-1}  .$$

I did a lot of simplification in the last equality, but I am sure you can work that out on your own. To solve your explicit problem, plugin and evaluate with r = 1.03, a = 3.5, and n=10 to get $$(3.5) \cdot \frac{(1.03)^{11} - 1.03}{(.03)} \approx 41.327.$$ Good question by the way, it is always good to be curious :)

Comment: Thank you, well explained.

Comment: You have made a mistake in your final calculation however, it's not 4.13 it's 41.3 trillion. It would be nice if it was 4.13.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I had a feeling using the iPhone calculator for that would be a bad idea. I changed it in my answer, but why do you say trillion? Is there application not mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, healthcare expenditures in 2017 in the US were 3.5 trillion (a 3.9% increase from previous year). I wanted to calculate over a 10 year period with a 3% increase to have an idea of the cost that we now know would be 41.327 trillion. On television we often hear about how medicare-for-all is too expensive at 32.6 trillion and we can't pay for it but this shows me that in fact it would cost almost 9 trillion more on the current system.
https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/NationalHealthExpendData/Downloads/highlights.pdf